# Unable to insert variable inside array

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
Grid = {{}, --first grid 
        {}, 
        {}}



for i=1,#Grid do
    local j = 0
    j = j + 1
    table.insert(Grid[i], _G["A"..tostring(j)] = {0, j} )
end
```

> Error:  Syntax error: main.lua:13: ')' expected near '='

Note: *I  couldn't think of any other way to fix the problem, I'm trying to insert the variable inside the array, so it would look like this*

```
Grid = { {A1={0,1},
{A2={0,2},
{A3={0,3} }
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Replace `table.insert(Grid[i], _G["A"..tostring(j)] = {0, j} )` with `Grid[i]["A"..tostring(j)] = {0, j}`